# Apply alert config for prometheus Alertmanager which is runnning on the kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a `kubernetes` cluster which running on `EKS`

I already installed `prometheus` and `alertmanager` from this [repository](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus.git).

This is the set of tools, so I think it is useful for a begginner like me.

Now I can see prometheus dashboad via `localhost:9090` and my pods are here.

There are somehow three alertmanager.(Maybe same as node?)

```
$kubectl get pod -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   aws-node-669m7                         1/1     Running   0          29m
kube-system   aws-node-7rwhg                         1/1     Running   0          29m
kube-system   aws-node-f7tnf                         1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system   cluster-autoscaler-78c99d7c59-6gbn7    1/1     Running   0          31m
kube-system   coredns-7dbf6bcd5b-5hgjx               1/1     Running   0          49m
kube-system   coredns-7dbf6bcd5b-ff5b4               1/1     Running   0          49m
kube-system   kube-proxy-jrwxh                       1/1     Running   0          29m
kube-system   kube-proxy-lwm9q                       1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system   kube-proxy-xp9l9                       1/1     Running   0          29m
monitoring    alertmanager-main-0                    2/2     Running   0          35m
monitoring    alertmanager-main-1                    2/2     Running   0          35m
monitoring    alertmanager-main-2                    2/2     Running   0          35m
monitoring    blackbox-exporter-69f4d86566-d99bk     3/3     Running   0          36m
monitoring    grafana-79cd8d4b69-2k9np               1/1     Running   0          36m
monitoring    kube-state-metrics-56f8746666-q298b    3/3     Running   0          31m
monitoring    node-exporter-ndln7                    2/2     Running   0          29m
monitoring    node-exporter-psqng                    2/2     Running   0          29m
monitoring    node-exporter-z92vx                    2/2     Running   0          35m
monitoring    prometheus-adapter-77f56b865b-4sgv7    1/1     Running   0          31m
monitoring    prometheus-adapter-77f56b865b-f9tx6    1/1     Running   0          35m
monitoring    prometheus-k8s-0                       2/2     Running   0          35m
monitoring    prometheus-k8s-1                       2/2     Running   0          35m
monitoring    prometheus-operator-54f6687b97-5mdbb   2/2     Running   0          35m
```

then, What I want to do is set the alert which send the email to my gmail account when nodes are more than 4.

so I made the `alertmanager.yml` (It is not the alert what I meant, this is just the sample, just practicing.)

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
  smtp_from: 'prometheus.test@example.com'
  smtp_smarthost: 'localhost:25'
route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receiver: 'web.hook'
  routes:
  - receiver: 'mailtest'
    match:
      test_type: SampleAlert
receivers:
- name: 'mailtest'
  email_configs:
    - to: 'root@localhost.localdomain'
      require_tls: false
- name: 'web.hook'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'https://127.0.0.1:5001/'
inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']
```

Then document says, I can attache this as `nohup ./alertmanager --config.file=alertmanager.yml &`

however, I don't have `alertmanager` command in my local PC.

How should I apply this yml to the alertmanager pods running on `EKS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/main/docs/customizations/alertmanager-configuration.md):
You can add Alert Manager configuration in your values.yaml file
under `values.alertmanager.config`
Alert manager is imported to kubernetes as a secret, if you want to se what is being applied, you need to run `kubectl get secrets` then extract data from it.

To do more complex manipulations on your configurations, you need to get familiar with [libsonnet](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/main/docs/customizing.md) .

Comment: Thank you very much!, I read the document, and maybe I god a first clue...

Comment: I made `my-kube-prometheus` as document says , then I compiled files under `manifest`  with `build.sh`. I am learning step by step. but, `values.yaml file under values.alertmanager.config` what does it mean? There is no values.yaml file and I couldn't find `values.alertmanager.config` even floder search.

Comment: I made the `alert-example.jsonnet` with this sample. `https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/main/docs/customizations/alertmanager-configuration.md` , then `sh build.sh alert-example.jsonnet`

Comment: However it made the wrong yml.....

Comment: you can add configuration to values in the jsonnet file you are intending.

Comment: bear in mind that you can use kube-prometheus-stack  [https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus] for easier and more automated operations.

Comment: THank you I will use that library as well, IT is still unclear for me, but thanks to your help, I can step forward.